# Do I need async/await even when I do not need to know the result?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, next.js

Say I have an API call which does X and I make it async/await:

```
export default async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {

    let success = await sendEmail({
    //...
    });


  return res.status(200).json({success: success});
};
```

I send back whether sending the email was successful or not.

But say I do not need to send anything back to the frontend: Will I still need `async/await` then? Would it be (minimally) faster to *not* use `async/await`? Or am I misunderstanding how `async/await` works?

Comment: If you don't care about the response then you don't need to use `await`.

Comment: You don't need to, if you don't use the return value in `success`

Comment: I doubt that there is a situation in which you don't want a result. You should always send an error code to the client if something broke

Comment: Unlike `await sendEmail();`, any errors would be unhandled promise rejections so you'd probably want `sendEmail().catch(...)` to at the very least log unexpected errors. As for "_faster_", if you don't `await` the result/exceptions of your async function then yeah, the rest of the script can finish sooner.

Comment: @Konrad: sending errors to the client is a business requirement and thus saying that it's *always* necessary ignores cases where it's not.

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't *have* to `await` if you don't care about the result; your understanding is correct. However, it's important that you do use `await` because if you don't, and the function `sendEmail` fails, you will not see the error. This can cause "uncaught exception" errors to be thrown, or if you have a `try {} catch {}` block somewhere, the failure of `sendEmail` will not be caught by it.